# Giveaway bot discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Everything works fine - embed sends but timer does not work and editing message while giveaway is over. This is my error:

```
Ignoring exception in command giveaway:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\222\dscbot-dscbot.py", line 70, in giveaway
    users = await msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
```

If someone could send this code but edited I would appreciate it. I know this question may be unclear I am new to discord.py.

```
from asyncio import sleep
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
from discord import Embed, TextChannel

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-", intents = intents)



@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def giveaway(ctx, duration: int, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, prize: str):
    reaction = discord.Reaction
    embed = Embed(title=prize,
                  description=f"Hosted by - {ctx.author.mention}\nReact with :tada: to enter!\nTime Remaining: **{duration}** seconds",
                  color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,)

    msg = await ctx.channel.send(content=":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:", embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")

    users = await msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(ctx.guild.me))
    

    while duration:
        await sleep(2)
        duration -= 2
        embed.description = f"Hosted by - {ctx.author.mention}\nReact with :tada: to enter!\nTime Remaining: **{duration}** seconds"
        await msg.edit(embed=embed)
    winner = random.choice(users)
    await ctx.send(f"**Congrats to: {winner}!**")
    embed.description = f"Winner: {winner.mention}\nHosted by: {ctx.author.mention}"
    await msg.edit(embed=embed)
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: can you add the whole traceback?

Comment: Added @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! 
The goal of asking questions is not to have someone else write your code for you, but to help you (and others) understand better what happens and what solutions to make it work.
Could you help us helping you by producing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of the whole code ?

Comment: @carmeldev that doesn't seem to be the full traceback

Comment: The comments about including the full traceback are because the traceback contains valuable information for diagnosing and solving your problem. While the error message is helpful, the traceback contains various other pieces of information, such as the line which caused the error.

Comment: There is no line specified in this error I just got this: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range. When I execute command embed send but timer does not work and error pops up. :U

Answer (score 0):

You made a few mistakes while formatting.

1. Embeds are defined with `discord.Embed`, not just `Embed`
2. `await sleep` should not be used, use `await asyncio.sleep` insted.
3. `reaction = discord.Reaction` is not really a call and not even used in your code, so also `channel: discord.TextChannel` which I removed.

It also looks like you are requesting the reactions in a false way. I had a similar problem and changed your code a bit.

Instead of `users = await msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()` we now use a different method:

```py
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import random

@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def giveaway(ctx, duration: int, *, prize: str):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=prize,
                          description=f"Hosted by - {ctx.author.mention}\nReact with :tada: to enter!\nTime Remaining: **{duration}** seconds",
                          color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color, )

    msg = await ctx.channel.send(content=":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:", embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)

    user_list = [u for u in await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if u != client.user] # Check the reactions/don't count the bot reaction

    if len(user_list) == 0:
        await ctx.send("No one reacted.") 
    else:
        winner = random.choice(user_list)
        e = discord.Embed()
        e.title = "Giveaway ended!"
        e.description = f"You won:"
        e.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await ctx.send(f"{winner.mention}", embed=e)
```

So what is new here is that we actually `fetch` the message by ID, which is an API call, but get all the information we need.

If you just want to edit the posted message simply use this:

```py
await new_msg.edit(content=f"{winner.mention}", embed=e)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but is there a method to edit this embed?

Comment: I got this error AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Comment: Did you copy the code and just edited the last line? If so this should not be the case.